# Flutter WebView with proxy

Tags: android, ios, webview, dart, flutter

I am trying to build app with webview that loads page with proxy. I need to change proxy programmatically (to set ip, port, username and password).

I had an idea to use **WebviewScaffold** *(flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.0+2)* and to override globally **HttpClient** like this:

```
class CustomHttp extends HttpOverrides{

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext securityContext){
    var client = new HttpClient();;
    client.findProxy = (Uri uri) {
      return 'PROXY XX.XX.XX.XX:{PORT};';
    };
    client.authenticate = (uri, scheme, realm) {
      client.addCredentials(uri, realm, new HttpClientBasicCredentials('username', 'password'));
    };
    return client;
  }

}
```

but with no luck. Looks like WebviewScaffold is not using global HttpClient.

Does anyone have an idea how can I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting the default header for all request in flutter HTTP requests.

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return new MyHttpClient(super.createHttpClient(context));
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You can specify your proxy settings in HttpClient class.

Comment: I have tried this way, but it is not working. webview is still not using proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't set a proxy to any webview on Android, that I'm aware of. :-(